# Setting height of image view in android

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I want to add a background image to my linear layout containg 2 text views.. I did that using a frame layout.. But the image is not scaling according to the size of my linear layout.. can anyone help ? The following is my layout file

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button_update_normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set background of linear layout by

```
android:background="imagename"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:background attribute of your LinearLayoutr. Set image as linear layout background.

Comment: did that.. i made the linear layout width to wrap_content.. still the image has height more than what is required for the two textviews..

Comment: in this case you have 2 approaches: 0. Specify height of root container (framelayout) and set fitXY scale type for you imageview. 1.use for background stretchable resource like nine-patch or like shape defined in drawables (this is the best approach).

Answer (score 0):

In your ImageView, change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you a simpler way. U don't actually need a framelayout to do wat you are trying to do. U can set your background image in your linearlayout itself. See the following code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background= "@drawable/yourBackgroundImage >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yeah but i want the height of the linear layout to not exceed the two textviews, but using this method (i changed layout_height to wrap content) the height is set as the height of the image which is larger, i want to scale down the height of the image...

Comment: Ohkk! I didn't quite get your problem initially. You could try "android:adjustViewBounds="true" in your <ImageView>. Also make all parent's & child's view width & height to "wrap_content" (i.e, FrameLayout, ImageView & your LinearLayout).

Answer (score 0):

android:background should work but this is another way to fit image acco

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/button_update_normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```